# Append to object in external JSON file javascript

Tags: javascript, json, append, external

i have an external file - file.json with values:

```
{
    "number": "value"
}
```

when I run a function, it goes and rewrites the file with new value. And I get:

```
{
    "number": "newValue"
}
```

what I would like to happen is to **append the data** to the previous file:

```
{
    "number": "value"
},
{
    "number2": "newValue"
}
```

How could I achieve something like this? I think I need to use .push(), but it gives me undefined.

This is the code that I am using at the moment.

```
var urlList = require('./urlList.json');

app.get('/hello', function(req, res){

  var cat = 5;
  catNumber = "number" + cat;
  url = urlList[catNumber];

  request(url, function(error, response, html){
     if(!error){
     var $ = cheerio.load(html);

     var number;
     var json = { };

     $('.content').filter(function(){
        var data = $(this);
        title = data.children().first().text().trim();

        json.number = url;

  })
}

fs.writeFile('file.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), function(err){
  console.log('File successfully written!');
})
```

Comment: Have you looked into [`fs.appendFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_file_data_options_callback)?

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you store your JSON in your file as an array like this:

```
[
    {
        "number": "value"
    }
]
```

Then you can read in the JSON as an array and then do your modifications on it:

```
let fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./file.json', (err, file) => {
  let jsonArray = JSON.parse(file);

  jsonArray.push({
    number2 : "newValue"
  });

  fs.writeFile('file.json', JSON.stringify(jsonArray));
});
```